# Any FSM/FSA Based Tagger

Tags: java, nlp, nltk, opennlp

There are several good taggers around. I even asked a question creating own [tagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921417/creating-own-pos-tagger),
I have got another requirement now. In Python I was using [topia](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/topia.termextract/) and it seemed a great choice for job (fast and concise). But there is no such alternative in Java,I could find.
Now, I have three questions related to this :

1)Is there any term extractor/pos tagger in Java which is based on FSM?

2) Is FSM tagger "CAN BE" more efficient (I know it is way faster, but accuracy) than corpus based taggers?

3) How Do I start building One in Java? Any basic guide creating machine extracting pos tags from sentence :- "Einstein was a great scientist." ? Just a start ?

Comment: Using a finite state machine (FSM) for tagging would (I suppose) imply that you merely look up the words (or pre-tagged phrases) in a dictionary. There would be no context-dependent disambiguation. Is that what you need?

Comment: yes, I infact don't even need a pos tagger. I need to analyze sentence like (if "to" comes at the last. Is sentence starts with "with" and ends with a word !="from". If "to" is in middle of sentence, what comes after 'to'. Like that.